# Сокрытие папок приложения для других приложений?

Tags: android

Существует ли способ сделать так, чтобы папки, которые создает мое Android приложения, не были видны и доступны в другом приложении. Например, мое приложение создало 2 папки с файлами. Я захожу через какой-нибудь файловый менеджер и они там не отображаются.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так не создавайте директорий в каталогах, доступных для всех приложений (sdcard и т.д.), используйте в качестве родительского каталога для ваших директорий результат вызова Context.getFilesDir() или Context.getCacheDir() (в зависимости от задачи).

Comment: Я создаю папки Encrypt и Decrypt там будут хранится зашифрованные файлы.

Comment: Окей, как-то так:

    File encryptDir = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "Encrypt");

Comment: У меня так создается.
sdPathEN = new File(sdPathEN.getAbsolutePath() +"/"+cr_dir_encr);
   if (!sdPathEN.exists()) {
    sdPathEN.mkdirs();
}

Answer (score 0):

ну классический способ ликукса начать имя папки с . (точки)

пример:

```
.i_am_invisible_folder
```

Comment: Не смешно.

Comment: а чем собсно вариант не походит?

Comment: Видимо тем, что при таком способе доступ к этим директориям другими приложениями остаётся возможным.

Comment: почему это? по тому же имени будет доступно.

Comment: Ну да, по имени будут доступны, в то время, как в вопросе чётко сказано "чтобы не были видны и доступны в другом приложении".

Comment: они не будут видны некому + положи в Context.getFilesDir() - без рута туда вообще не доберутся

Comment: Да, это и есть мой ответ :)

В вашем же варианте (начать имя с точки) каталоги эти будут доступны всем желающим + видны в файл менеджере (естественно, если там стоит опция show dot files), что противоречит условиям вопроса.

Comment: ну так автор не уточнил зачем ему прятать папку, если там что-то шифрованное хранить твой вариант не лучше получается...

Comment: Почему не лучше? Как вы сами чуть выше верно подметили, при размещении в getFilesDir() другие приложения получат доступ лишь при наличии рута. А при наличии рута все способы бессильны.

Comment: Папки прятать,чтобы нельзя было из других приложений их удалить или файлы лежащие в них.